# PHP Insert seeming to rollback

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

It seems to me that this is not committing its work. It says that it inserts the data, and it get back an incremented id. However its not in the database. Am i missing a call to commit the work after executing the statement?

```
        <?php 
//Make connection
$con = mysqli_connect('xxxxxxx','xxxxxxxx','xxxxxxxxx') ;


/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

//change db to andriodnfp db
mysqli_select_db($con, 'andriodnfp');

$date = htmlspecialchars($_POST["Date"]);

$temperature = htmlspecialchars($_POST["temperature"]);
$temperature = !empty($temperature) ? "'$temperature'" : "NULL";

$Stamps = htmlspecialchars($_POST["Stamps"]);
$Stamps = !empty($Stamps) ? "'$Stamps'" : "NULL";

$Fertile = htmlspecialchars($_POST["Fertile"]);
$Fertile = !empty($Fertile) ? "'$Fertile'" : "NULL";

$Period = htmlspecialchars($_POST["Period"]);
$Period = !empty($Period) ? "'$Period'" : "NULL";

$Intercorse = htmlspecialchars($_POST["Intercorse"]);
$Intercorse = !empty($Intercorse) ? "'$Intercorse'" : "NULL";

$Cervix = htmlspecialchars($_POST["Cervix"]);
$Cervix = !empty($Cervix) ? "'$Cervix'" : "NULL";

$Mood = htmlspecialchars($_POST["Mood"]);
$Mood = !empty($Mood) ? "'$Mood'" : "NULL";

$Headache = htmlspecialchars($_POST["Headache"]);
$Headache = !empty($Headache) ? "'$Headache'" : "NULL";

$Pregnancytest = htmlspecialchars($_POST["Pregnancytest"]);
$Pregnancytest = !empty($Pregnancytest) ? "'$Pregnancytest'" : "NULL";

$Energy = htmlspecialchars($_POST["Energy"]);
$Energy = !empty($Energy) ? "'$Energy'" : "NULL";

$Notes = htmlspecialchars($_POST["Notes"]);
$Notes = !empty($Notes) ? "'$Notes'" : "NULL";

$user_id = htmlspecialchars($_POST["user_id"]);
$user_id = !empty($user_id) ? "'$user_id'" : "NULL";

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT _id FROM CHARTING WHERE Date=? AND user_id=? ORDER BY _id LIMIT 1")) {
    /* bind parameters for markers */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $date, $user_id);

    /* execute query */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /* bind result variables */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $_id);

    /* fetch value */
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

    /* close statement */
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}



if (!empty($_id)) {
    //Date already exists do update

    /* create a prepared statement */
    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "UPDATE CHARTING SET temperature=?, Stamps=?,  Fertile=?,  Period=?, intercourse=?, cervix=?,  mood=?,  headache=?, pregnancytest=?, energy=?, Notes=? WHERE $_id =?")) {

        /* bind parameters for markers */
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssssssssssss", $temperature, $Stamps, $Fertile, $Period, $Intercorse, $Cervix, $Mood, $Headache, $Pregnancytest, $Energy, $Notes, $_id);

        /* execute query */
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

        /* bind result variables */
        $posts = array('auto_increment_id'=>$_id);

        /* close statement */
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
} else {
    /* create a prepared statement */
    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO CHARTING ( Date, temperature, Stamps, Fertile, Period, intercourse, cervix, mood, headache, pregnancytest, energy, Notes, user_id)
                                        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")) {

        /* bind parameters for markers */
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssssssssssss", $date, $temperature, $Stamps, $Fertile, $Period, $Intercorse, $Cervix, $Mood, $Headache, $Pregnancytest, $Energy, $Notes, $user_id);

        /* execute query */
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

        /* bind result variables */
        $posts = array('auto_increment_id'=>mysqli_insert_id($con));

        /* close statement */
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }
}


mysqli_close($con);

$posts = array($posts);
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('posts'=>$posts));

?>
```

Comment: your logic seems to be backward - if `$result` is empty, you should insert, not update, right?

Comment: You absolutely correct. The insert works now, only thing is the update doesn't get the auto_increment_id

Comment: Is this all the code? Did you check your error logs?

Comment: It seems the mysqli_insert_id is incorrect for updates, what can i use instead. @Mike Purcell yes it is.

Comment: Instead of an extra `SELECT` at the start, how about [`INSERT INTO table ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: think my answer does what you need, or yeah @sammitch's method is the best

Comment: TBH I think sgroves response is the better answer, as he should be updating rows based on primary key, not on a date column. Which means he should already know the id of the record being updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `mysqli_insert_id` only gets the last id *inserted* (not updated). But that's fine—if you're inside the block where you run the `update` statement, you (can) already know the id. Just add it to your earlier `select` statement:

```
SELECT _id, Date FROM CHARTING WHERE Date=? AND user_id=? ORDER BY _id LIMIT 1
```

Then when you update, you can simply update the row containing the id (instead of selecting by date):

```
UPDATE CHARTING SET temperature=?, Stamps=?,  Fertile=?,  Period=?, intercourse=?, cervix=?,  mood=?,  headache=?, pregnancytest=?, energy=?, Notes=? WHERE _id =?
```

This has the added benefit of updating the field based on a primary key (`_id`) rather than the date. The latter is bad because two rows might have the same date. In general, you should always make updates based on primary keys (e.g. `where _id =?`), which will always be unique.

Comment: Awesome! I made the adjustments... See above.

Comment: looks good except in your update statement you want `where _id=?` not `where $_id=?` – otherwise `$_id` will get interpolated, causing your sql statement to contain, e.g. if `$_id` is `5`, `where 5 = 5`, which is not what you want.